# Best way to build a desktop app while keeping my python

Tags: python, user-interface, desktop-application

So, I've built this program using python what is currently running in the terminal.

My goal is to eventually design the application in a modern way like (discord, slack, or any other 2021 downloaded desktop-app),but I'm not really sure what to use.

The thing is, I know React/Electron would be the best way to build/design a desktop application like discord, teams etc. However, I'm looking to keep my python as some sort of backend, while using lets say Electron as front

How can I keep my python functions, while designing a modern GUI/front end?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 3):

`wiki.python.org` has [GuiProgamming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) entry, where GUI frameworks for python are enumerated. You need to select framework which does support platform you are targeting. If you are interested in fine control of look I would suggest [Kivy](https://kivy.org) cross-platform framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Tkinter python module although it is not to much like react.

Comment: Yea, I've heard about Tkinter. Isn't it very old school though, and could it be used to design modern sleek GUIs?

Comment: Yes it may be a little difficult to make modern and sleek GUIs but it is extremely easy to use but there are other options that I have not tryed myslef. I'm not to sure on how to use it but i've heard that flask and django modules can be used as well although a little difficult to set up.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about Django. Not sure if it can be used for other than for web development though.